# Electron sending file by socket.io-stream failed with 'TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk'

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, electron

I'm creating an app with Electron. I was need to sent file to server with Socket.IO, so I installed socket.io-stream module. I tested on browser, it works well. But do same in Electron, it always fails with

> TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk

This is server side code:

```
ss(socket).on('/user/update/profile', (stream, data) => {
    const filename = path.basename(data.name);
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(`userdata/profile/${filename}`);

    stream.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log('Error found:');
        console.log(e);
    });
    stream.on('drain', (e) => {
        console.log('drain');
    });
    stream.on('data', () => {
        console.log('data');
    });
    stream.on('close', () => {
        console.log('close');
    });
    stream.pipe(ws);

    //ss(socket).emit('/user/update/profile', {});
});
```

And this is client side code:

```
var file = ev.target.files[0];
var stream = ss.createStream();

ss(socket).emit('/user/update/profile', stream, {
    email: this.props.user.email,
    name: file.name,
    size: file.size
});

var blobStream = ss.createBlobReadStream(file);
var size = 0;
blobStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    size += chunk.length;
    console.log(`${size} / ${file.size}`);
});
blobStream.pipe(stream);
```

code is quite simple, just from the example in module's introduction page on NPM. I already said that it worked as browser. You see that I logged every file uploading progress on the console. Using Electron, sending file seems to work because it logged every data size, but on server side, it fails.

I found similar issue with NW.js and that guy solved his problem with his own way but that didn't worked for me.

It will be very appreciate help me how should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means your are passing a non-string (e.g. an object) where a string is expected.  I cannot see where that might be offhand but since it works in the Browser but not Electron it might be that the underlying Javascript engines have a different tolerance for the issue.  Can you run the same in a node debugger?  Does one of the streams complain or break oddly?  Can you narrow down which line this is coming from?